# Uniform convergence and cauchy sequence

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis

if I have a sequence $(x_n) \subset (C[0,1],||.||_{\text{max}})$ such that
$sup_{s \neq t} \frac{|(x_n(t)-x_m(t)) - (x_n(s)-x_m(s))|}{|s - t |},s,t \in [0,1] $ is convergent to zero. And we have that $||x_n - x ||_{max} \rightarrow 0$.

Can we somehow show then that $sup_{s \neq t} \frac{|(x_n(t)-x(t)) - (x_n(s)-x(s))|}{|s - t |} $ is convergent to zero?

Comment: What does "such that $\sup \dotsc$ is convergent ot zero" mean? Does it mean that for all $\varepsilon > 0$ there is an $N$ such that for all $n,m \geqslant N$ we have $\sup \dotsc \leqslant \varepsilon$?

Comment: yes, you are right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us define $\DeclareMathOperator{\lip}{lip}$

$$\operatorname{lip}(f) := \sup \left\lbrace \frac{\lvert f(t) - f(s)\rvert}{\lvert t-s\rvert} : s,t\in[0,1],\, s\neq t\right\rbrace.$$

Then $\operatorname{lip}(f) \in [0,\infty]$ for all $f$, and on the space of functions where it is finite, $\operatorname{lip}$ is a fine seminorm.

When you have $\lim\limits_{m,n\to \infty} \operatorname{lip}(x_n-x_m) = 0$, in the sense

$$\bigl(\forall \varepsilon > 0\bigr)\bigl(\exists N\in \mathbb{N}\bigr)\bigl(n,m\geqslant N \Rightarrow \lip(x_n-x_m) \leqslant \varepsilon\bigr),$$

then pointwise convergence of $x_n$ to $x$ implies $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \lip (x_n -x) = 0$.

Let $\varepsilon > 0$ be given, and choose an appropriate $N$. Fix arbitrary $s\neq t \in [0,1]$. Then

$$\frac{\lvert x_n(t) - x(t) - x_n(s) + x(s)\rvert}{\lvert t-s\rvert} = \lim_{m\to\infty} \frac{\lvert x_n(t) - x_m(t) - x_n(s) + x_m(s)\rvert}{\lvert t-s\rvert} \leqslant \varepsilon$$

for $n \geqslant N$ by the pointwise convergence. Since $s,t$ were arbitrary, we have $\lip(x_n-x) \leqslant \varepsilon$.